# Why I see instant clicks from Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I don't know it is the right place to ask or not. But I have this doubt. When I post something on twitter, I see some 9-10 instant clicks on that link. I get this everytime. I searched a lot about this but couldn't find possible answers. Anybody know why this happening?

Comment: I imagine this is at least part due to Twitter's attempt to detect any malicious links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are likely to be bots.  Twitter publishes an instant feed of new tweets.  You can watch this feed if you want.  I know that Google watches this feed.  It sends googlebot out to instantly crawl new links that are tweeted.  Some people are using this as a quick way to get new content indexed: you tweet it and Google crawls it.    It would not surprise me if there were a bunch of other crawlers watching the twitter feed in a similar manner.